# How to disable recaptcha in react-native-firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

Recently I have updated `@react-native-firebase/auth`, and now there is `Recaptcha verifier` added to the updated version.

But I dont want, even I didnt configure any `Recaptcha` but it is automatically opens while signing with phone number in `react-native` and this is not a good experience.

**How can I disable it, is that possible ?**

Answer (score 5):

To disable reCaptcha in firebase auth, we have to enable SafetyNet

There are two steps to enable SafetyNet :

first, add SHA-256 key in project settings in firebase console
then enable google phone verification in the google cloud

To enable Android phone verification follow the below steps

goto https://console.cloud.google.com/

go to APIs & Services

go to Library

search go Android Device Verification

simply enable it

for this, you can check out the official doc of firebase phone authentication

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

Comment: Thank you very much, will this avoid the Recaptcha in production mode, I mean for release version?

Comment: Yes, This will avoid Recaptcha if we have done all steps precisely according to documentation.