# How to avoid recaptcha in Firebase Authentication in React Native Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I install firebase from react-native firebase

```
# Using npm
npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app

yarn add @react-native-firebase/auth
```

code which send OTP to the user number:

```
    async signUpOTP(obj) {
      console.log('signInWithPhoneNumber', obj);
      const { number, pin, confirmPin } = this.state
      let prefix = '+92' + number;
      auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(prefix)
        .then((confirmationResult) => {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('@signItem', JSON.stringify(obj));
          this.props.navigation.navigate('signupcode', { 'confirmationResult': confirmationResult, 'number': number, 'pin': pin, 'confirmPin': confirmPin })
          this.setState({ visible: false });
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error, 'catch me');
          let invalidError = 'Invalid Number';
          toastMsg(invalidError)
          this.setState({ visible: false });
        });
    }
```

However, it shows a Re-captcha screen instead of sending OTP code

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this Recaptcha screen?

Comment: It seems others have asked this question before, and gotten answers that you might want to try: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+avoid+recaptcha+in+Firebase+Authentication+in+React+Native+Firebase+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Let me check. Hope, it will be helpful

Comment: Thanks, @FrankvanPuffelen below link resolve my issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65846534/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-react-native-firebase

Comment: Good to hear @Qamber 