# How do I resend verification code for firebase phone number auth

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

There seems to be only one function for sending verification code and it requires captcha. That's understandable for the first sign in but what if the user wanted a resend. Doing recaptcha again is a bit of a hassle.

Anyway, here is my code for sendVerificationCode

```
    const sendVerificationCode = (completePhoneNumber: string) => {
        signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, completePhoneNumber)
    .then((confirmationResult) => {
      // SMS sent. 
      // ...
    }).catch((error) => {
      // Error; SMS not sent
      // ...
    }).finally(() => {
        });
    }
```

I tried looking into official docs but nothing seems to fit the description. I understand that the code doesn't expire until 15 mins but still I wanted to implement this because sometimes the code doesn't deliver.

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/19855bw/how_do_i_resend_verification_code_for_phone/

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no resend functionality in Firebase Phone Auth. You have to call the same function again.

And regarding the captcha, you can disable that from the cloud console

reference links=>

[How to disable recaptcha in react-native-firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65846534/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-react-native-firebase)

[How to disable reCaptcha in firebase phone-auth (OTP) android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999106/how-to-disable-recaptcha-in-firebase-phone-auth-otp-android)

Comment: Would it be possible for the sendVerification to have a captcha while the function implementation for the resendVerification to have none?